# Pre-render Markdown to HTML in Angular

Tags: angular, markdown, prerender

I'd like to be able to pre-render my Markdown files into HTML for my Angular site. Right now I'm using ngx-markdown, which does the conversion at runtime. It just seems like a big waste for everyone's browsers to have to make this conversion when the content is essentially the same on every page load. Perhaps this is a symptom of wanting a static site even though I'm using Angular.